# Docker compose installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, docker, docker-compose

In my docker image I am cloning the git master branch to retrieve code. I am using docker-compose for the development environment and running my containers with volumes. I ran across an issue when installing new project requirements from my python requirements.txt file. In the development environment, it will never install new requirements on dev environment because when re-building the image, the latest code is pulled from github.

Below is an example of my dockerfile:

```
FROM base

# Clone application
RUN git clone repo-url
# Install application requirements
RUN pip3 install -r app/requirements.txt

# ....
```

Here is my compose file:

```
myapp:
    image: development
    env_file: .env
    ports:
        - "8000:80"
    volumes:
        - .:/home/app

    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Is there any way to install newly added requirements after build on development?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

### By hand

You can enter the container and do it yourself. Downside: not automated.

```
$ docker-compose exec myapp bash
2912d2cd9eab# pip3 install -r /home/app/requirements.txt
```

### Using an entrypoint script

You can use an entrypoint script that runs prep work, then runs the command.

**Dockerfile:**

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

# ... probably other stuff in here ...

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/app
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# May as well do this too, while we're here.
python3 manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

The entrypoint is run like this at container startup:

```
/entrypoint.sh $CMD
```

Which expands to:

```
/entrypoint.sh python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The prep work is run first, then at the end of the entrypoint script, the passed-in argument(s) are exec'd. That's your command, so entrypoint.sh exits and is replaced by your Django app server.

**UPDATE:**

After taking comments to chat, it came up that it is important to use `exec` to run the command, instead of running it at the end of the entrypoint script like this:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I can't exactly recall why it matters, but I ran into this previously as well. You need to exec the command or it will not work properly.

Comment: nice solution. upon installing all requirements, the server never seems to start. it appears no logs are being dumped to stdout.

Comment: Notice that the script changes to the `/home/app` directory - perhaps that is not where your `manage.py` is located? Your Dockerfile didn't show the WORKDIR, so I am not sure what the image is assuming. Maybe you simply need to `cd` somewhere else before running the exec.

Comment: WORKDIR is set to /home/app. Confirmed it by running 'ls' in the entrypoint script. Appears to be in the correct location.

Comment: @RobertChristopher Oops! I forgot an important bit... you need to set `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile. See updated answer.

Comment: Am I supposed to specify entrypoint in the compose file? thanks.

Comment: You can specify entrypoint and/or command in the compose file, those will override whatever the image itself has. The image always has an entrypoint whether you specify it or not; it defaults to `/bin/sh -c` if you don't tell it what to use. Using the CMD and ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile builds it into the image, and in that case you don't need either in docker-compose.yml unless you want to override the image.

Comment: Still encountering issue in which python manage.py runserver returns nothing to stdout. Server doesn't appear to boot either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Attached (docker attach) to the running container and sent ctrl + c keys. Something on the process seems to be blocking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131818/discussion-between-robert-christopher-and-dan-lowe).

Comment: @RobertChristopher Updated the answer to include one detail that emerged in chat (exec).

Answer (score 11):

The way I solved this is by running two services:

1. server: run the server depends on requirements
2. requirements: installs requirements prior to running server

And this is how the docker-compose.yml file would look like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  django:
    image: python:3.7-alpine
    volumes:
     - pip37:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
     - .:/project
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /project
    command: python manage.py runserver
    depends_on:
      - requirements

  requirements:
    image: python:3.7-alpine
    volumes:
      - pip37:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
      - .:/project
    working_dir: /project
    command: pip install -r requirements.txt

volumes:
  pip37:
    external: true
```

PS: I created a named volume for the pip modules so I can preserve them across different projects. You can create one yourself by running:

```
docker volume create mypipivolume
```